# Finding the correct rounding value to output non-0 values

Tags: r, rounding

I have a vector of decimal numbers ranging from -10 to 10 with different decimal depth.

I would like to output a rounded version of this vector so that all numbers are rounded at the level of the decimal number which last shows a non-0 decimal (e.g. 0.0040 shows a non-0 decimal after 0.1000, the rounding should be 3). My goal is to always output non-0 values after rounding my vector.

In the following example, the decimal number showing a first non-0 value is 0.000100, thus all numbers should be rounded to 4. The value `1.000002` should not be rounded to 6 because it is already different to 0.

```
### Initiating vector of values, only 0s and 1s should be displayed because the deepest decimal level is 4. 2s should not be displayed
tmpVector <- c(0.111120, -11.011102, 0.001100, 0.000100, 1.000002, -0.101022)

### Correct rounding
round(tmpVector, 4)

[1] 0.1111 -11.0111   0.0011   0.0001   1.0000  -0.1010
```

I would like to find an automatic method where I can replace `round(tmpVector, 4)` with `round(tmpVector, deepestLevel)`.

Couldn't find other versions of `round()` function taking care of this problematic.

Comment: I think this problem can be solved by finding the minimum absolute value of those numbers in (-1, 1). The issue is that R interprets numbers in its scientific notation and it is not easy to find  where the non-zero value appears.

Comment: Thank you, the regex formula seems to work for the example but it doesn't work for the following one: `tmpVector <- c(0.000001, 0.1)` -> `0`. Ps: I think you removed your comment

Comment: It may not be appropriate for your presentation, but this seems an ideal candidate for scientific notation?

Comment: @Paul I agree it could be interesting with scientific notation but unfortunately it makes it hard to read for people outside of scientific field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so we can extract the lowest exponent like so:

```
tmpVector[tmpVector!=0] |> # remove zeros
  abs() |> # some values are negative - we don't care
  log10() |> # log gives us the exponent
   min() |>  # find the smallest
  floor() |> # make an integer
  abs() # stop it being negative

# gives:
4
```

then incorporate that into `round()`:

```
round(tmpVector, tmpVector[tmpVector!=0] |> abs() |> log10() |> min() |> floor() |> abs())
[1]   0.1111 -11.0111   0.0011   0.0001   1.0000  -0.1010
```

or avoiding pipe notation:

```
round(tmpVector, abs(floor(min(log10(abs(tmpVector[tmpVector!=0]))))))
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a less convoluted way to do this, by the way.  I just don't know it.

Comment: It's only convoluted because you're using pipes.  This is a case where standard notation looks simpler (to me, at least):  `abs(floor(min(log10(abs(tmpVector)))))`. By the way, the code will fail if there are any zeros; they should be removed first.

Comment: That's true, I hadn't considered that zeros would be an issue.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the explanation. I updated the code with the following to make sure it works with 0s: `abs(floor(min(log10(abs(tmpVector[tmpVector!=0])))))`

Comment: @user2554330 incorporated the suggestion for avoiding zero values and non-pipe notation, thank you.